# jQuery's POST triggers "done" but no data is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I want to submit my form with AJAX. I wrote a function for triggering this with pushing the button:

```
function putUser() {
    $('button#putUser').on('click', function() {
        var user = $('input#user').val(),
            amount = $('input#amount').val(),
            what = $('input#amount').val(),
            country = $('input#country').val(),
            platform = $('input#platform').val(),
            formUrl = $('form#sendUser').attr('action');

        var data = {
            user: user,
            amount: amount,
            what: what,
            country: country,
            platform: platform
        }

        $.post(formUrl, $('#sendUser').serialize(), function() {
            alert('test');
        }).done(function() { alert('done')})

        return false;
    })
}
```

This theoretically works, because I'm getting `done` alert. But no data is being submitted. What's wrong? My SQL statement works just fine.

My php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['putUser'])) {
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    $what = $_POST['what'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    $platform = $_POST['platform'];

    $query = mysql_query('INSERT INTO sells (id, user, amount, what, country, platform) '
        . 'VALUES (NULL , "' . mysql_real_escape_string($user) . '", "' . mysql_real_escape_string($amount) . '", "' . mysql_real_escape_string($what) . '", "' . mysql_real_escape_string($contry) . '", "' . mysql_real_escape_string($platform) . '")');

    if($query) {
        echo 'ok';
    } else {
        die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you confirming that *"no data is being submitted"*? can we see your server-side code?

Comment: Nothing new appears in my sql table.

Comment: That doesn't mean no data is being submitted. For all we know your sql query could be failing, or you could be incorrectly accessing the post data. your javascript is correct.

Comment: Data is being submitted using regular PHP and page refresh when JS is turned off.

Comment: There we go. you aren't sending a putUser post var when you use the `data` to send it, and i'm guessing jQeury isn't serializing your button value.

Comment: If you change `.done(function() { alert('done')})` to `.done(function(data) { alert(data);})`, does anything get alerted?

Comment: I feel so silly now :D But how can I send "button press" by AJAX?

Comment: rather than using a button for that, use a hidden input. or better yet, use a GET param instead for that particular variable.

Comment: Works great! I should've thought of this before ;) Thank you Kevin! Please post this as an answer, so I can accept and "+1" it :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change putUser param to a get param.

```
<form action="sendUser.php?putUser">
```

php

```
if(isset($_POST['putUser'])) {
```

js

```
function putUser() {
    $('#sendUser').on('submit', function() {
        var formUrl = $(this).attr('action');

        $.post(formUrl, $(this).serialize(), function() {
            alert('test');
        }).done(function() { alert('done')})

        return false;
    })
}
```

Also changed to a submit event rather than click, which allowed me to further use `this` rather than a selector.

Answer (score 1):

What is `$('#sendUser').serialize()`? is that a form you built you `data` of?

**EDIT**:
Try dataType 'json' for post - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Serialised content of the form.

Comment: You may want to use data object that you built to post it.

Comment: I did. I still don't see why would you create data object and not use it ever later.
You may need to add 'json' as a last parameter for post request:

$.post(formUrl, $('#sendUser').serialize(), function() {
            alert('test');
        }, 'json');

On a side note, i suggest to use "ajaxError" to trace and see if there were any troubles with ajax request - http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're actually sending the data you want to submit.

Note that `$('#sendUser').serialize()` has been changed to your `data` object. And that `putUser` has been added to `data` so that the server side code recognizes it.

I think you want this:

```
function putUser() {
    $('button#putUser').on('click', function() {
        var user = $('input#user').val(),
            amount = $('input#amount').val(),
            what = $('input#amount').val(),
            country = $('input#country').val(),
            platform = $('input#platform').val(),
            formUrl = $('form#sendUser').attr('action');

        var data = {
            putUser: true,
            user: user,
            amount: amount,
            what: what,
            country: country,
            platform: platform
        }

        $.post(formUrl, data, function() {
            alert('test');
        }).done(function() { alert('done')})

        return false;
    })
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried using `$.post(formUrl, data...)` before.